# Lazy load a list that is obtained from a using statement

Tags: c#, .net

I am using CSVHelper library to read from a CSV file. But that's not what this is about

Please refer to the code below

```
public class Reader
{
    public IEnumerable<CSVModel> Read(string file)
    {
       using var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\z0042d8s\Desktop\GST invoice\RISK All RISKs_RM - Copy.CSV");
       using var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
       IEnumerable<CSVModel> records = csv.GetRecords<CSVModel>();
       return records;
    }
}
```

The csv.GetRecords in the above method uses a yield return and returns every CSV row as soon as it's read and not wait until the entire CSV file is read to return (Streams data from the CSV)

I have a consumer class which as the name suggests consumes data returned by the Read method.

```
class Consumer
{
   public void Consume(IEnumerable<CSVModel> data)
   {
      foreach(var item in data)
      {
         //Do whatever you want with the data. I am gonna log it to the console
         Console.WriteLine(item);
      }
}
```

And below is the caller

```
   public static void main()
   {
      var data = new Reader().Read();
      new Consumer().Consume();
   }
```

Hope I didn't lose you.

The problem I am facing is below

As data variable above is IEnumerable, it will be Lazy loaded (In other words, it doesn't read the CSV file as long as it's not iterated over). But, by the time I call the Consume() method, which iterates over the data variable, forcing the reading from the CSV file in the Read() method, the reader and csv objects which are in using statements will be disposed off throwing an ObjectDisposed exception.

Also, I don't want to remove the reader and csv objects outside of the using blocks as they should be disposed to prevent memory leaks.

The exception message is below

```
    System.ObjectDisposedException: 'GetRecords<T>() returns an IEnumerable<T> 
    that yields records. This means that the method isn't actually called until 
    you try and access the values. e.g. .ToList() Did you create CsvReader inside 
    a using block and are now trying to access the records outside of that using 
    block?
```

And I know I can use a greedy operator (.ToList()). But I want the lazy loading to work.

Please suggest if there are any ways out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't the using keyword supposed to define a code block ? `using(var x = ) { /* code in scope */ }`

Comment: @SteveB starting with C# 8, not anymore. C# 8 introduced [using declarations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/using#using-declaration), which is just some syntactic sugar that generates the using block automatically, making it so you don't have to any more.

Comment: @MindSwipe: good to know. It means the disposed is implicitely called at the end of outerscope ?

Comment: @SteveB yes correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can lazily enumerate items from GetRecords IEnumerable and yield records to the consumer like this:

```
public class Reader
{
    public IEnumerable<CSVModel> Read(string file)
    {
        using var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\z0042d8s\Desktop\GST invoice\RISK All RISKs_RM - Copy.CSV");
        using var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        foreach (var csvRecord in csv.GetRecords<CSVModel>())
        {
            yield return csvRecord;
        }
    }
}
```

This way you guarantee to enumerate records before the underlying data gets disposed and you don't need to load all data up front.

Comment: It worked!  When I saw this comment, I didn't believe it would work. But when I implemented it, it did. Realized that if a function has yield return keywords, no code inside the function executes until iterated over. Brilliant!

Comment: @VarunShridhar you may want to consider "accepting" one of these answers so the user can receive credit

Answer (score 3):

You may pass an action as parameter to the reader. It changes a bit the approach thought:

```cs
public class Reader
{
    public void Read(string file, Action<CSVModel> action)
    {
        using var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\z0042d8s\Desktop\GST invoice\RISK All RISKs_RM - Copy.CSV");
        using var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        
        IEnumerable<CSVModel> records = csv.GetRecords<CSVModel>();

        foreach(var record in records){
            action(record);
        }
    }
}

class Consumer
{
    public void Consume(CSVModel data)
    {
        //Do whatever you want with the data. I am gonna log it to the console
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var consumer = new Consumer();
    new Reader().Read(consumer.Consume); // Pass the action here 
}
```

ALternatively, you can make the whole Reader class Disposable :

```cs
public class Reader : IDisposable
{
    private readonly StreamReader _reader;
    private readonly CsvReader _csv;

    public Reader(string file)
    {
        _reader = new StreamReader(file);
        _csv = new CsvReader(_reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public IEnumerable<CSVModel> Read()
    {
        return csv.GetRecords<CSVModel>();                   
    }

    public void Dispose() => Dispose(true);

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (disposing)
        {
           _csv.Dispose();
           _reader.Dispose();
        }

        _disposed = true;
    }

}

class Consumer
{
    public void Consume(IEnumerable<CSVModel> data)
    {
        foreach(var item in data)
        {
             //Do whatever you want with the data. I am gonna log it to the console
             Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    using var myReader = new Reader("c:\\path.csv");
    var consumer = new Consumer().Consume(myReader.Read());
}
```

Comment: Oh that's brilliant.